# Is it possible to query the process list for Time > N in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

In MariaDB (+ MySQL) you can do `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to get a list of queries in the queue/running. One of the useful things is the `Time` field.

I'm finding I have some awful queries that are triggered and sit there consuming resources long after anyone's interest has moved on.

I'd like to be able to do "SHOW PROCESSLIST WHERE Time > 3600" to find queries that are live and have been running over an hour, but it's a syntax error.

I've also tried `SELECT * FROM (SHOW PROCESSLIST) x WHERE Time > 3600` to no avail.

Is there a way? (Obviously in an ideal world I'd be able to track down what's responsible for the dodgy queries!)

I'm on MariaDB 10.1.41

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run the query against the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST` table like so:

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST where Time > 3600;
```